# Even with e.preventDefault(), $.post is taking me to the form action path when I click a submit button

Tags: jquery, preventdefault, .post, form-submit, ajax-forms

Every time I  click any of the submit buttons, the post request works, and the php file in the form action successfully carries out the MySQL query, but the use is taken to a blank page with the address of the form action php file, and the callback function of the post request is not called. I first tried `return false` at the end of submit's callback function, then `e.preventDefault()`, and neither has helped.

Some other info: the dataType is set to json because if it isn't, the `$.post` request doesn't get executed. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#maintenance_form").submit(function(e){
  $.post($("#maintenance_form").attr("action"), $("#maintenance_form").serialize(), dataType: "json", function(data){ alert("You have successfully submitted your change."); });
  e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Comment: Try to use a javascript console. I guess your submit function has some errors, that's why you're still being redirected

Comment: Just used one, and it didn't find any problems.

Comment: where does your ajax post to? Did you define that globally or did you forget to?

Comment: It posts to the path listed in the form's action attribute. The path is valid, and the form is submitted properly. Its just what the page does after the submission that causes problems.

Comment: does your .php return json?

Comment: I do it something like this: http://pastebin.com/9hTgrb2T

Comment: It doesn't return or echo anything.

Comment: that may be the problem, try it like i posted

Comment: I had something like that earlier. The same thing happened, but whatever json encoded stuff I echoed just showed up in the browser.

Comment: I have no idea then, if you want me to check it out myself, I can

Comment: maybe add an alert("test") before the ajax, to see whether you bound the submit action correctly

Comment: maybe your whole javascript is never called. Are you sure you didn't misstype the id='maintenace_form' of the <form> element etc. ?

Comment: The form gets submitted. Otherwise, the database would not have been changed according to the values I entered, and the result of clicking a submit button would not be my browser displaying the PHP page that is referenced by the path in the action attribute of my form tag. I don't want the browser to go to the PHP page. I want it to stay where it is. That is the problem.

Comment: Oh, never mind. That's exactly what it would do. It must be that the dataType: "json" argument is causing a syntax error?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rP06HXiH   working one i use. sends a POST with $_POST['nonce'] = nonce etc. sorry for that awful pastebin format

Comment: did it work like that?

Comment: Not quite. It is still going straight to the form handler, which is a blank page in a web browser because it's a PHP page that doesn't have any echo statements. If I include the form handler in the page and change the action to $_PHP['SELF'], it goes back to the original page, but refreshes without updating the display values. This is the problem I am trying to get around using ajax, so I am back to the beginning again.

Comment: Also, I have tried taking the action attribute out of the form tag and putting it only in the argument list for the ajax request so that I know the form submission is going through ajax. The form submission is still successful, so its going through the ajax method, but the quasi-refresh problem still occurs, and it never reaches the call-back function, just like before.

Comment: Also, if I put the address for the form handler only in the ajax request and have 'return false' or called the preventDefault() function after the ajax request, the ajax request does not go through and the form submission is unsuccessful.

Comment: well, did you try echoing json on the php script?

Comment: Yes, it just shows the blank page with the json encoded info at the top left corner in black text.

Comment: Basically, either the callback function is successfully called or the query is successfully made, and I don't understand why both aren't happening.